# How to replace a text in file?

Tags: python

Basically I am trying to replace A with B, I manage to to change the first line, then the two other lines get deleted and it throws an error:

```
replace_txt = replace_txt[search_txt]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

My text:

```
A is best
A is cool
A is awesome
```

My code:

```
import fileinput

replace_txt = {'A':'B'}
for line in fileinput.input('text1.txt', inplace=True):
    for search_txt in replace_txt:
        replace_txt = replace_txt[search_txt]
        line = line.replace(search_txt, replace_txt)
    print(line, end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
replace_txt = replace_txt[search_txt]
```

overwrites your lookup dictionary with a string. So the next time round `replace_txt` is no longer a dictionary so selecting using `[ ]` gives you an error.  Call your lookup dictionary something else.